# using a decimal separator different from my actually culture info

Tags: angular, typescript, cultureinfo

I was assigned a bug that keeping the culture of windows 10 on Italian and changing from the control panel the decimal separator could not on our website to display the numbers with it.
is there any way to tell devextreme, keeping the translation of the grid in Italian, to use the comma defined by the operating system? 
I would also like to ask if you could tell me what to study to understand the interaction between the culture of the operating system and that of my website?

Answer (score 0):

There is a function for that `.toLocaleString()`

```
const myNumber = 300.012;
console.log(myNumber.toLocaleString())
```

Consider creating a pipe for this if you are using Angular

Comment: X.tolocalestring() reference to the culture used by the website, not the One used by windows10